# Из-за чего возникает такой баг?

Tags: android, google-chrome, slider, touch

Android Google Chrome 89

Появляется белая полоска при прокрутке сайта, в тот момент, когда исчезает верхний бар с адресов, в момент, когда отпускаешь палец, событие touchend

Почему и как? При отключении слайдера все нормально становится, слайдеры менял на разные, не помогло

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6961843/111463958-3d81dc00-8731-11eb-907a-bde39dc1acf2.mp4

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6961843/111463903-2c38cf80-8731-11eb-8181-9235fec9cccc.mp4

Тестовым путем определено, баг начинает проявляться, только когда подключаешь файл со скриптом, с любой строкой кода

Comment: [Скрытие полосы прокрутки в WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7088997)?

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов не, по всей видимости ТС не полосу прокрутки имеет ввиду, а белую полосу шириной с ActionBar внизу экрана, которая появляется буквально на долю секунды при скрытии ActionBar'a хрома.